# Trouble with Jquery Animate not finishing it's animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a fair bit of animation running on my page, and I think its causing this particular animation to stutter, and then not finish its animation some of the time.

I have written this to animation some percentage bars on the page.

I have tried adding a timeout function so that it gives the other animation some time to finish up, however the timeout doesnt work and it seems to fire off immediately after the page loads. Any help making sure my percentages finish would be amazing

```
function dopercentage()
{
  $('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
  var progress = $(this);
  var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
  $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing:'swing',
    step: function() {
      // What todo on every count
    var pct = '';
    if(percentage == 0){
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
    }else{
      pct = Math.floor(this.countNum+1) + '%';
    }
      progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
    }
  });
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout( dopercentage(), 1000);
});
```

Here is a HTML example of what should be animated, but failed at 91%

```
<div id="bar-5" class="bar-main-container" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background:#cb0050;max-width: 250px;">
        <div class="wrap">
          <div id="bar-percentage13" class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="100">91%</div>
          <div class="bar-container">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 91%;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please create a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `dopercentage()` immediately, then passing the result to setTimeout.

`setTimeout` requires a function *reference*, not the result of a function call.

Just pass the function reference (name):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout( dopercentage, 1000);
});
```

Aside from that, I just had to remove the initial 91% text from the sample. When the code was not firing I wound up with your test value :)

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/Ly3vj12d/1/

Comment: Thanks, the width is not actually in the base code, just what i copied when i pasted the code in from the screen grab.

The problem i have is when my page has more then on object to animate, every object only animates up to some random number between 91%-99%.